# Rails Ajax call to another controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is the first time I've used Ajax and I'm pretty lost. I'm looking to call the index method of my company_pays controller from a view governed by the companies controller. The aim is to replace the div `company_content` with the `index` data returned from the AJAX request that's triggered when they click the `<%= link_to " Payments", company_pays_path(current_company), :method => :get, remote: true %>` . Here's my code so far:

> **views/companies/company_home.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>

  <h1></h1>
  <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li>
                    <li><%= link_to " Edit Company", edit_company_path(current_company), :method => :get %></li>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <li><%= link_to " Payments", company_pays_path(current_company), :method => :get, remote: true %>
                    </li>
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-static-side -->  

<% end %>


<h1><%= current_company.name %></h1>

<div id="company_content"></div>
```

> **views/company_pays/index.js.erb**

```
$('#company_content').update('<%= j render ("company_pays(current_company)") %>');
```

> **controllers/company_pays_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @company_pays = CompanyPay.where(company_id: current_company.id).order(:id) 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end

end
```

I've been looking at this for hours but am getting nowhere. I'm guessing that the problem is in the index.js.erb file but I've no idea how to do it properly. Can anyone help?

Thanks for looking

> **Edit 1**

I got this working but I'm not 100% sure why.

I changed the following lines:-

> **views/companies/company_home.html.erb**

```
 <li><%= link_to " Payments", company_pays_path(current_company), :method => :get, remote: true %></li>
```

**changed to**

```
 <li><%= link_to " Payments", company_pays_path, :method => :get, remote: true %></li>
```

> **views/company_pays/index.js.erb**

```
$('#company_content').update('<%= j render ("company_pays(current_company)") %>');
```

**changed to**

```
$('#company_content').html('<%= j (render "index", collection: @company_pays) %>');
```

I then created the file views/company_pays/_index.html.erb and copied the code from the main index page.

This is working but I'm not 100% sure why. Can anyone help:-

1. In `index.js.erb` if I add the words `render partial: "index"`, it lists the company_pays 3 times. There are a total of 3 in my database so I guess it has something to do with that but I can't figure out why it's rendering all 3,in 3 separate blocks.
2. In `index.js.erb` it's rendering the file '_index.html.erb' even though the code is `render "index"`. I've checked this to make sure it's actually rendering the partial and it is but I can't understand why.

At least it's working. Thanks to all for helping.

Comment: Please see by inspecting if the following link's href attribute has pointed to the action you desired
 `<li><%= link_to " Payments", company_pays_path(current_company), :method => :get, remote: true %>`

Comment: Do you really need to render js instead of html in the index method?

Comment: The HTML being generated is `<li><a data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="/company_pays.9"> Payments</a>` so I guess that's where the problem is but I'm not sure how to fix it. I want the index method to return only company pays that belong to the current company i.e. 9. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm also unsure if I need to render js instead of html in the index method. This is the first time I've used AJAX so I've just been copying what I can find online and they all use js. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
Read this, it may help you

Comment: I read that yesterday but in reality, it's not very helpful. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

j is shortform of javascript_tag

```
javascript_tag "alert('All is good')"
```

Returns:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
alert('All is good')
//]]>
</script>
```

And in the following code, the `company_pays` and `current_company` might not be defined, so they are creating problem. In `:remote => true` with `server side js`, the problem is that its very difficult to find bugs.

```
$('#company_content').update('<%= j render ("company_pays(current_company)") %>');
```

also, I think you can render a partial and sending the values such as current_company and company_pays along with it

```
$('#company_content').update('<%= render 'company_pays' locals: { current_company: current_com} %>');
```

Comment: I'll look into rendering a partial but I'm a bit confused with them as I don't understand the difference between rendering a partial and rendering a page. If I move my code to a file in `views/company_pays` called `_index.html.erb`, why will this work instead of calling the page directly?